# Add calculation in declared string

Tags: excel, vba

i am still learning VBA excel, and i faced a problem, how am i going to add adding calculation in my code

```
vRow = 2
While Cells(vRow, 1).Value <> ""
field1 = Cells(vRow, 1).Value
field2 = Cells(vRow, 2).Value
field3 = Format(Now(), "AB""_""YYYYMMDD""_""001")
field4 = Cells(vRow, 4).Value

Dim str As String

str = ""
str = field1 & "|" & field2 & "|" & field3 & +1 & "|" & field4
```

My current results outcome is something like this

```
00|?????|AB_20161215_0011|
```

i need the field 3 to be able to +1 instead of the first results outcome

```
00|?????|AB_20161215_002|
```

I almost Got it

```
Dim str As String
Dim calc As Long
calc = 1 + 1

str = ""
str = field1 & "|" & field2 & "|" & field3 & calc & "|" & field4
```

It's just that the format i can't make it to 002 instead of 2,

```
00|?????|Ab_20161216_2|
```

Additional info: i need the format able to cater till 999 like

```
00|?????|AJ_20161216_999|
```

Comment: You are trying to add a number to a text string.  You will need to pull the last three into a Long variable then you can add to it and then concatenate it into the string.

Comment: yeah, i almost got it scott, but the thing is how am i going to make it 002 instead of 2

Comment: Dim calc As Long
  calc = 1 + 1

Comment: You already have the method: `Format(calc,"000")`

Comment: Thank you so much Scott for your guidance.. i got it now...